# 500 error.Internal[backend error] Google Api Push #gmail_watch

Tags: .net, gmail-api

I tried to get notifications using the guide Here. 
 https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#gmail_watch

Gmailservice(service) is able to get Labels,Inbox and other api features.

Here is the code.

```
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
    });
    IList<string> label = new List<string>();
    label.Add("INBOX");
    WatchRequest request2 = new WatchRequest
    {
        LabelIds = label,
        LabelFilterAction = "include",
        TopicName = "projects/******/topics/****TestTopic"
    };
    var x= service.Users.Watch(request2, "me").Execute();
```

Watch Throws This Exception

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Backend Error [500]
Errors [
    Message[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
]
```

Answer (score 10):

OK, mine is solved.
Yes, I agree, the error message from gmail API is somewhat obscure, but here is how I have fixed it.

Apparently, I forgot to grant *Push* permissions to gmail.
To do so go [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/cloudpubsub/topicList) and do the following:

- Select your project.
- From the tab on the right, grant push rights to `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`.

Good Luck!

Comment: Well ,I did give Editor Permission to service acccount earlier and I think that should be okay.Please correct me if i'm doing wrong

Comment: Not sure what _Editor_ permissions gives, but to rule it out - you can try grant _Publisher_ permissions, which did the trick for me.